# What is the recommended database schema of a table backing a message store?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm looking to utilize Spring Integration's Resequencer and am trying to create a message store to back it.  We're using SQL Server as our DB solution.

When looking at the documentation, I don't have a good understanding about what my message store table should (or could) look like:

[17.4 JDBC Message Store](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store)

In the snippet from the documentation below, it looks like there are options with the ":" syntax to insert and/or query on message attributes.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway
update="insert into foos (id, status, name) values (:headers[id], 0, :payload[foo])"
request-channel="input" reply-channel="output" data-source="dataSource" />

<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway
update="insert into foos (status, name) values (0, :payload[foo])"
request-channel="input" reply-channel="output" data-source="dataSource"
keys-generated="true"/>
```

So is there a comprehensive list of token names?  Is "id" acting as a hash into a headers map?  Does it correspond to a message header called "id"?  For ":payload[foo]", what is "foo" representing?  Are there recommended column types that align with the different message attributes?

I'm really looking for guidance on:

1. What my database schema should be? (what are my options)
2. How do I map into and out of this schema in my SI configuration?  (i.e., how to tell SI which parts of the message go to what columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schemas are in the jar, and can be found [in the github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc).

You need to use the schema corresponding to the version of Spring Integration you are using.

Yes, `headers[id]` means the `id` header.

`payload[foo]` assumes the payload is a `Map` and has a key `foo`.

You can use any SpEL expression for example, an object with `getFoo()` can use `payload.foo`.

The gateways don't act on the message store - they act on your business table(s).

Answer (score 1):

The `spring-integration-jdbc` jar contains these scripts: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/jdbc

Where you can find a script for the SQL Server.

The `<int-jdbc:message-store>` component utilizes operations for around those tables.

In the end you just need to you that bean a a reference to the appropriate components, e.g.:

```
<resequencer message-store="jdbcMessageStore">
```

It isn't recommended to manupulate `MessageStore` tables manually: only using `JdbcMessageStore`.